# I trying to create a table in MySQL database using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a table in my MySQL database. Here's my code:

```
//Table
public static void createTable() throws Exception
{
    try {
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement create = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE   IF NOT EXIST registration(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,first_name varchar(45),last_name(45),email varchar(320),password varchar(50),PRIMARY KEY(id))");
        create.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("System Updated");
    };
}
//End of Table
```

This is the error I'm getting

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXIST registration(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,first_name varchar(45),last_name(45),email var' at line 1

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS`, not `IF NOT EXIST`

Comment: `last_name(45)` should be `last_name varchar(45)`. copy the sql statement and execute it on sql command prompt, it will give you more details. If the query is running then drop the table and copy it in java source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong with this query:

1. It should be `if not exits`, with an "s" at the end.
2. The `last_name` column is missing a type (presumably `varchar`?)

Put it all together, and your SQL should look like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS -- First issue
registration
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 first_name VARCHAR(45),
 last_name  VARCHAR(45), -- Second issue
 email VARCHAR(320),
 password VARCHAR(50),
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot.That worked

Answer (score 0):

`first_name varchar(45),last_name(45)`

last_name doesn't have a data type associated with it

try 
`last_name varchar(45)`

Answer (score 0):

Your last_name column is missing a data type and EXISTS is incorrcetly spelt. You have left off the 's'.